# Split a column value into Multiple columns based on an ID in R

Tags: r, dplyr, split, multiple-columns, data-transform

I have a dataset that has different timepoints for each ID. I want one record per ID where I want the timepoints to be split in different columns . I dont want to use spread as I want the actual value of the column. Some of the IDs have 14 records per ID and I want 14 them split across 14 columns. How can I achieve this in R ?

sample data

| ID | Timepoint | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | yes |
| A | 2 | yes |
| A | 3 | yes |
| A | 4 | yes |
| B | 7 | yes |
| B | 11 | yes |
| C | 4 | yes |
| C | 5 | yes |
| D | 7 | yes |

| ID | Timepoint1 | Timepoint2 | Timepoint3 | Timepoint4 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | yes |
| B | 7 | 11 |  |  | yes |
| C | 4 | 5 |  |  | yes |
| D | 7 |  |  |  | yes |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tidyverse**

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(id_rows = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider( 
    id_cols = c(ID, Value),
    names_from = id_rows,
    values_from = Timepoint,
    names_prefix = "Timepoint"
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

*output*

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  ID    Value Timepoint1 Timepoint2 Timepoint3 Timepoint4
  <chr> <chr>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
1 A     yes            1          2          3          4
2 B     yes            7         11         NA         NA
3 C     yes            4          5         NA         NA
4 D     yes            7         NA         NA         NA
```

Answer (score 4):

We may use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), ID + Value ~ paste0("Timepoint",
       rowid(ID)), value.var = 'Timepoint')
```

-ouptut

```
  ID Value Timepoint1 Timepoint2 Timepoint3 Timepoint4
1:  A   yes          1          2          3          4
2:  B   yes          7         11         NA         NA
3:  C   yes          4          5         NA         NA
4:  D   yes          7         NA         NA         NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"D"), Timepoint = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 7L), Value = c("yes", 
"yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 2):

in Base R:

```
 reshape(transform(df1, time = ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq)), 
          dir = 'wide', idvar = c('ID', 'Value'), sep='')

  ID Value Timepoint1 Timepoint2 Timepoint3 Timepoint4
1  A   yes          1          2          3          4
5  B   yes          7         11         NA         NA
7  C   yes          4          5         NA         NA
9  D   yes          7         NA         NA         NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the finest way, but it works: combination of `splitstackshape` and `data.table`. The other solution are already presented:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)

df <- dcast(getanID(df1, 'ID'), ID~.id, value.var='Timepoint')
colnames(df)[2:5] <- paste("Timepoint", colnames(df)[2:5], sep = "")
```

Output:

```
   ID Timepoint1 Timepoint2 Timepoint3 Timepoint4
1:  A          1          2          3          4
2:  B          7         11         NA         NA
3:  C          4          5         NA         NA
4:  D          7         NA         NA         NA
```